# Chrome are not able to access iPhone Camera with react-qr-reader - npm

Tags: reactjs, iphone, react-native, npm, camera

The below is code of React

```
<QrReader
      delay={300}
      onError={this.handleError}
      onScan={this.handleScan}
      style={{ width: '100%' }}
/>
```

The link works fine on all Browsers in Android device, also works fine on Safari browser of iPhone devices, but it does not even ask camera permission for other Browsers like Chrome and Firefox on iPhone Devices.

Comment: iOS: 11.2.1 - The problem persists..

Answer (score 1):

The docs say Known Issues. On IOS 11 it is only supported on Safari and not on Chrome or Firefox due to Apple making the API not available to 3rd party browsers. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-reader

Comment: I have gone through attachment. If so, I think there is a way to access camera with html5 on iOS device.